# How to LEFT JOIN on a table defined in a table column

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

Consider the following tables:

User Table

```
id | name | createdAt  |
-----------------------|
1  | John | 2018-02-02 |
```

Activity Table

```
id | itemId | itemTable | createdAt  |
-------------------------------------|
13 | 1      | User      | 2018-02-02 |
14 | 142    | Client    | 2018-02-02 |
```

I want to be able to `LEFT JOIN` on a table specified in the column:

```
SELECT    b.* 
FROM      activity      AS a 
LEFT JOIN *a.tablename* AS b 
ON        b.id = a.itemid
```

for MemSQL or MySQL

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: No, no, no, no. You should not do this. SQL should only be dynamic if you have absolutely no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in a `SELECT` query.  SQL does not operate this way.

If you know there are only two tables, you can express the query like this:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM USER u 
WHERE u.id = (SELECT 1 FROM activity a WHERE  a.itemid = u.id) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT c.* 
FROM client c 
WHERE c.id = (SELECT 1 FROM activity a WHERE  a.itemid = c.id);
```